# Sh скрипт на создание screen

Tags: ubuntu, sh

Хочу сделать sh скрипт, который бы создавал несколько скринов в ubuntu. Сначала создается скрин, внутри него выполняется две команды:

1. cd servers/velocity
2. sh start.sh

И так скрипт заходит в несколько директорый в директории servers и запускает start.sh
Попробовал написать это, но выдает ошибку. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#!/bin/sh

screen -S velocity -d -m
screen -r velocity -X stuff $'cd servers/velocity\n'
screen -r velocity -X stuff $'sh start.sh\n'
```

UPD:
Попробовал написать скрипт: screen -dmS velocity sh -c "cd servers/velocity; sh start.sh"
Сама команда делает то, что мне нужно. Но если я ее закидываю в скрипт и этот скрипт запускаю, то ничего не работает

Comment: Кто-где-как-когда запускает скрипт? Каков текущий рабочий каталог в момент запуска?

Comment: Файл находится в юзере (xlalbertlx). Это и есть каталог. В нем есть сам скрипт и папка servers, внутри которой папка velocity. Скрипт пытаюсь запустить командой sh start.sh. В ответ получаю : not found: